# Proof convergency of series $a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n!} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have used Cauchy and came to step where i have $\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(n+p)!} $ i cant find upper boundary $ \epsilon $ , hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance !

P.S. Sorry for potencial grammar mistakes, English is not my native language.

Comment: Do you have to prove it's a Cauchy sequence? The ratio test is enough to prove convergence.

Comment: Can i say at this point thet series is going to 0(don't know english term) so from there i can say that it's Cauchy sequence/series so from there i can prove convergence ?

Comment: No. From the ratio test, it is bounded from above by a *convergent*  geometric sequence, hence (as all its termes are positive) it is a convergent sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: The "tail" is less than the sum of the geometric series
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^3}+\cdots\right).$$

Comment: So i should write $$\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(n+p)!} < \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^3}+ \cdots\right). $$ ? What should i do next ? And thanks for help !

Comment: That's fine. I gave an unnecessarily "sharp" inequality. But now note that the sum is $\le \frac{1}{(n+1)!}(2)$, which is $\le \frac{2}{(n+1)}$. That makes finding a suitable $N$ given $\epsilon\gt 0$ easy.